# Trying to replace the bathroom exhaust fan with a new fan and heater. How do I go about it from where I am now?

Tags: bathroom, mold, ventilation

I have small whole bathroom with an older ventilator fan that has a heater with it. Unfortunately it's dead altogether so basically I have to replace the whole thing and so far have removed the ventilator itself to where I'm through the ceiling and could potentially install the new one though I don't feel confident in doing it seeing that this would be the first time I've ever done it. The main reason I need to replace it is to help minimize the chance of mold growing within the bathroom tile. The fan in replacing is an older model that I can't even find online.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd share more photos but it didn't allow for more than three.

Comment: Does this bathroom have an HVAC supply duct into it? If it does, then manually switch the fan to "ON" for 1 hr after showering/bathing. This will greatly help drying out the bathroom. Your current fixture is not an exhaust fan, only a circulator/heater.

Answer (score 4):

The old fan looks like just a heater with a fan to blow warm air.  There is no evidence that it has ventilating properties.

The new fan is a ventilating fan that directs air to the outside. It is not an easy swap.

You will need to cut a hole in the ceiling, do electrical work, light framing for the fan support and access to you attic or between floors.  Ducting will need to be run and a termination port placed on the roof or through a sidewall.

If none of that gives you pause, check a few YouTube videos.  If any part does make you nervous, call a handyman or HVAC company and hire them to install the new fan.

Comment: Just to add, your jurisdiction might require a dedicated circuit for the heater.